# Concrete Mathematics: Generalised Josephus binary expansion

Tags: discrete-mathematics

On page 11 (of the second edition) they give an example of the binary expansion of $n$:

$$
n = b_m2^m + b_{m-1}2^{m-1} + ... + b_12 + b_0
$$

and then say

> where each $b_i$ is either 0 or 1 and where the leading bit $b_m$ is 1.

I don't understand what they mean by $b_i$ - where does the $i$ come from? Do they mean the "index" of the particular bit we're looking at?

Comment: Yeah it's the index when reading the binary number from right to left. The index here starts at $0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b$_i$ is a sloppy way of writing a function b:{0,1,..m} -> {0,1}.
$b_m2^m + b_{m-1}2^{m-1} + ... + b_12 + b_0 = \sum_{i=0}^m b(i)2^i$

Comment: So the authors are implying the series you have given as an example? Hence the $i$ by convention?

Comment: It is a variable like x. @FredClausen